Lucas numbers in polar coordinates: why does this monstrosity of a graph happen?
The other day I've been bored and was messing around in Desmos. I've had a silly idea: what kind of spiral would I get if I put down Fibonacci or Lucas numbers in polar coordinates? I've plotted a list of dots in which the radius is equal to the corresponding number in the Fibonacci sequence, and in which the theta is equal to the corresponding number in the Lucas series (not rounded to the nearest number), then connected all the dots with straight lines. (Precision from 15 to 19.9995, 10000 iterations)
And what I saw was quite intriguing.

So many questions. Why are there certain sectors of the whole graph? Why is there a circle in the middle of it? Why is there a line cutting through the entire thing at 45°? Would love if someone broke it down and explained it.

What does "connected them all with lines" mean? What does the picture look like if you just plot the dots $(F_n, L_n)$ in polar coordinates? Those sequences grow at the same exponential rate $\varphi$.

@EthanBolker Here's how just the dots look like. And yes, they do grow at the same exponential rate phi. However I don't round the Lucas numbers, they're just phi to the power of n.

Your problem is in taking the Lucas number as the angle. While the radial Fibonacci term is growing regularly, the angle Lucas term, now interpreted as radians, is growing wildly and bouncing all around between 0 and $2pi$. Hence you will not see a smooth spiral arise.

@CyeWaldman I knew that a smooth spiral wouldn't happen, that's why I tried it in the first place. But I got confused on how split apart it looked, as if it had its own sectors. And also I got confused by the practically 45° line, as I've noticed there are multiple overlaying onto it which makes it look thicker.
